# Sending custom data via OAuth (specifically LinkedIn API)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm using the LinkedIn API to authenticate users. After authentication LinkedIn posts data back to my app at `/auth/linkedin/callback` (as is the OAuth standard).

I also offer other auth methods (e.g. Google+, Twitter, etc..). If the user signs in with one of those, I want them to also be able to (on top of their existing auth) connect with LinkedIn to pull in additional data.

In those cases, I want the callback URL to be something different so I don't have to do some very custom `if...then` logic.

1. Is there a way to specify in an OAuth request where you want to call back to?
2. If #1 isn't possible, can I send some custom arbitrary data or flags with my initial request that are returned during the callback? That way when parsing the response I'll check those flags for the appropriate state of the User and redirect them as necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: According to the OAuth 2.0 Specification, It should work. Have you tried it? You would need to register your OAuth Client with the "associated" redirection URI with each Authorization server. If during the registration you specify the FULL redirection URI, then it is optional within the Authorization Request.

Answer (score 0):

The `state` parameter is guaranteed to be preserved across all interactions. You can store (encoded?) information in it, and when the final callback is called, you will get back the original value you sent.

A common use case is capturing the "end URL" for the user (like a deep link into your app that requires auth).

You are supposed to check that what you receive is exactly what you sent.